# Call powershell comands from bat file / cmd comand and keep running to the next line

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, volume

I have a script to turn off monitors as I leave the computer (I want to do it manually, yes)

simple as:

```
timeout 5 /nobreak

echo Turning off...

powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

works almost great, except as I turn on (moving mouse, for example), the cmd window keeps open

now I want to silence the computer also, so I added :

```
powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x319,-1,0x90000)
```

but as soon as one instruction got executed, it doesn't continue to the next one

not sure what should I do or search...

Comment: You appear to have escaped double-quotes, even though they're not nested within another set of double-quotes, which I'd assume is incorrect. Also as single-quotes mean nothing special to cmd.exe, _(they're just standard characters)_, your caret, `^`, could become an issue, because that is a special character to cmd.exe, _(an escape character)_.

Comment: There's nothing too difficult about running a `powershell.exe` command in `cmd.exe`. Begin the command with `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command ""`. Then in between those two double quotes insert your working PowerShell command. Now before you run it, you'll need to escape any inserted double quotes with a backward slash, and any percent characters with another percent character. So if the following worked in PowerShell, `Write-Host "foobar"`, your command would look like this in your batch file `…powershell.exe -Command "Write-Host \"foobar\""`.

Comment: Now to start an executable, in this case `powershell.exe`, but not wait until it has finished, i.e. keep running the next command, you'd use the `start` command, i.e. `Start "" "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "Write-Host \"foobar\""`.

Answer (score 0):

This "blank my monitor" because the boss is coming, has been bandied about in different guises for a long time, since posted on TechNet. However, it is not usually combined with a second call thus runs OK as a one liner.

When combined in a sequential batch process the commands need to be started without a pause thus in such cases we can spawn two commands using `Start "Title" Command`

The first gripe is but a console command shows a console window when running so the simplest solution in this case is run the script(s) either Taskbar `/MIN`imised or `/B`lank

```
@echo off & echo Turning off Audio ^& Video in... & timeout 5 /nobreak

Start /B "Audio Off" powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x319,-1,0x90000)

Start /B "Video Off" powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

If you want to Maximise the CMD to initially Cover UP faster once its triggered, then try this in place of the first line.

```
@echo off & Color 02
if not "%1" equ "1" start /max "Turn off" "%~f0" 1
if not "%1" equ "1" exit
echo(&echo  'Turning off Audio ^& Video in...' & timeout 5 /nobreak
```

However from a programming aspect that may be considered playing dirty.

**AND** you will need an **extra `Exit`** on the line **after** the second `Start /B`

You are better advised to **Start** the first example above with your shortcut etc. as

`Start /MAX "Turn Off" TurnOff.cmd` or whatever you call it